# How to populate itemTemplates of TemplateField in gridview from datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The table I am querying from has 3 fields, all varchar, but 2 of them are base64String from image and video files. I have added a gridview such:-

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img id="image" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a id="downloadLink" runat="server"></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I searched a lot but have no clue on how to populate the Template field column from a dataTable. I need to set the src attribute of the  from database query and also need to set innerHTML for the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img src='<%#Eval("image_source")%>' runat="server" />
                    <a id="downloadLink" runat="server"><%#Eval("anchor_content")%></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Where image_source and anchor_content are assumed to be the columns returned by your SQL query.